# how can I check an empty variable in php with &nbsp value?

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$string
```

if I print it nothing return to me:

```
echo $string; // result in browser: blank!  in html source code:&nbsp
```

I try use this code to undererstand $string is empty!

```
if ($string!= '&nbsp' && $string!= ' ' && $string!= '' && $string!= null && $string!= '  ' && !empty($string))
echo 'true';
else
echo 'false';
```

But  It always return me 'true', why? //I think in $string there many space or sth like that

Comment: What do you assigned to `$string`?

Comment: your logic is wrong. Consider if $string is "&nbsp" - it's not ' ' so it evaluates to true! Doesn't matter what $string is, it match one of those tests!

Comment: `$string` cannot be `&nbsp` while being empty at the same time. I think that you meant to use the `||` `or` operator instead of the `&&` `and` operator.

Comment: only plaintext...No html tags include

Comment: you could also simplify the if statement by `if(!(isset($string) || trim($question) === '' || $string != '&nbsp;')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked it, this should work:

```
$strings = ['', ' ', '&nbsp;', 's', 's ', '&nbsp;s'];

foreach ($strings as $string)
{
    $string = trim(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $string));

    if (strlen($string) != 0)
        echo $string . ' is not empty';
    else
        echo $string . ' is empty';

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
is empty
is empty
is empty
s is not empty
s is not empty
s is not empty
```

Comment: You're right, what about `strlen()` instead of `empty()` ?

Answer (score 0):

A more robust method might use this as a starting point...

```
//correct entities
$plain=html_entity_decode($string);

if (preg_match('/[^\s]/', $plain)) {
   //string contains some non-whitespace
}
```

Comment: Yeah, had my Perl head on there. Edited since then anyway!

Comment: trim will not work:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-notes

Comment: It would have worked in the code PeeHaa commented on